# Error onInfoWindowClickListener, not launching a new activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I'm trying to launch a new `Activity` when the user press the info window of a marker on the map;
however i tried to do another thing for testing such as change the text in the info window `onClick` but its not working too.

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent("com.test.app.MAINACTIVITY"));

    }
});
```

Comment: how about posting a stacktrace ? or try this startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MAINACTIVITY.class));

Comment: Thank you Rajesh ur comment was right in place :) it worked once i tried another activity it was a mismatch in the manifast.

Comment: Okay bro keep going ;)